# WSL2 host cannot connect to QEMU using network bridge

Tags: networking, qemu, wsl-2, kvm, bridge

I'm using WSL2 and I want to connect it to QEMU. And here's my operation:

1. The ip address of WSL is: 172.21.71.177/20
2. Then I create a network bridge which address is 172.21.71.178/20

```
$ sudo brctl addbr virbr0
$ sudo ip a a  172.21.71.178/20 dev virbr0
$ sudo ip l set dev virbr0 up
```

3. Open QEMU and run the kernel. I assign 172.21.71.179/20 to QEMU.

```
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -netdev bridge,id=en0,br=virbr0 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=en0 -append "netdev.ipv4_addr=172.21.71.179 netdev.ipv4_gw_addr=172.21.71.178 netdev.ipv4_subnet_mask=255.255.240.0 --" -kernel build/02-httpreply_qemu-x86_64 -nographic
```

However, when I want to ping 172.21.71.179 in WSL2, it shows "Destination Unreachable". Can someone tell me where I make mistakes? Thank you so much!
(The work I do is referring https://unikraft.org/community/hackathons/sessions/baby-steps/#02-building-and-running-the-httpreply-application)